# ¿Qué significa "Microservice chassis"?

Tags: microservices

He estado profundizando sobre los distintos patrones que se abordan en una arquitectura de microservicios. En la página [microservices.io](https://microservices.io/patterns/index.html) se describen los patrones oficiales del apartado "Cross cutting concerns".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo el patrón "Service Template", que es básicamente tener un template de una estructura básica de microservicio para que cuando vayas a crear nuevos microservicios, sea más rápida la configuración inicial. Mi duda entra en el patrón "Microservice chassis", no entiendo la diferencia ante el patrón antes nombrado. Alguien me podría explicar?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El *Service Template* incluye el *microservice chassis*:

Por ejemplo, usando Java es típico usar *Spring Boot + Spring Cloud*: Añades un par de dependencias y éstas, a su vez, incluyen todo lo necesario para montar un microservicio: autenticación, acceso a bases de datos mediante JPA, anotaciones para crear recursos REST con una decena de líneas, obtener la configuración de un repositorio común a todos los microservicios... etc.
Esto es el chasis o esqueleto básico de todos los microservicios.

El template es la parte que activamente copias y pegas: el `pom.xml` si usas Maven o `build.gradle` si usas Gradle con las dependencias genéricas, más los ficheros de configuración básicos que tu organización requiere: URLs para acceder al LDAP o a las bases de datos, por ejemplo, o scripts a ejecutar durante el despliegue para terminar de configurar el contenedor/máquina en cada entorno, quizá el fichero `.gitignore` personalizado...

La principal diferencia es que el template puede ser algo genérico que tendrás que modificar para cada proyecto (por ejemplo, el nombre del servicio), mientras que el chasis no requiere ninguna modificación.

Comment: Entendí perfectamente, muchas gracias.